# Modifying veriwell simulator

Tags: c

I am trying to modify veriwell to do some fully homomorphic encryption stuff. The problem I encounter is that veriwell optimizes the duplicated inputs by bypassing them, i.e: 
          if in TIME1 there are two inputs (N1 = 0, N2 = 1), 
         and in TIME2 the inputs change to (N1 = 0, N2 = 1), 
In this scenario, veriwell does not evaluate N1 = 0 in TIME2, instead it bypasses it, which conflicts the operation needed for FHE.

I tried to modified the source codes, by changing the "notify" function located in store.cc as follows:

```
void notify(tree LVAL, enum logical_value STATE, int CHANGED, tree pc)
{
/* Currently, pc is null only on PLI calls to here */
    if (pc) {
    DECL_UPDATE_FILE(LVAL) = STMT_SOURCE_FILE(pc);
    DECL_UPDATE_LINE(LVAL) = STMT_SOURCE_LINE(pc);
    }
    ASSIGNTIME64(&DECL_UPDATE_TIME(LVAL), &CurrentTime);
   // if (DECL_EVENT_CHAIN(LVAL) && (CHANGED))          // original code
    if (DECL_EVENT_CHAIN(LVAL))                         // added
         NotifyEvent(DECL_EVENT_CHAIN(LVAL), STATE, deferred);
}
```

The parameter "CHANGED" which indicates the change of inputs has been disabled in order to trigger the event, but still the gate evaluation is not executed...

Any solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: As you can see, this function jumps to "NotifyEvent" which is contained in "schedule.cc", and then I totally get lost...